# Thunderbird freezes after updated to 38.3.0

Tags: thunderbird, mozilla

I use Ubuntu 14.04 , after I updated thunderbird to 38.3.0, it freezes after a while of opening it , any idea how to fix this without losing my current setting?

Comment: Same here on 15.04

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the calendar plugin Lightning 4.0.3. The previous version 4.0.2.1 seems to work fine.

Comment: I have disabled it and nothing happens , still the same problem

Comment: Do you have the FireTray addon?

Comment: yes v 0.5.6.1-signed

Comment: I have disabled FireTray and it fixes my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have disabled **Firetray v 0.5.6.1-signed** and thunderbirds works fine now